# How to upsert multiple rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to write a query like this in PostgreSQL 9.5.2:

```
INSERT INTO a (id, x)
    SELECT id, x FROM b
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
    SET x = b.x
    WHERE b.y < 100
```

but I get `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "b"`. I must be missing something basic, but how do I refer to the row being inserted in the UPDATE clause? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The conflicting values are available through the [`excluded`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) alias:

```
INSERT INTO a (id, x)
SELECT id, x 
FROM b
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
    SET x = excluded.x;
```

Comment: Amazing answer, was hard to find and provides a super elegant solution to the multiple row upsert problem. Thanks!